# Zero to the negative power.

Tags: calculus, number-theory

The zero to the negative power is undefined. Am I right?

Comment: there Comes an error, it is not defined

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, what is the difference between`undefined` and `not defined`?

Comment: i think $0^{-2}$ is not defined

Comment: surely one can also say it makes no sense

Comment: and what is the right answer to your question?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, as far as I know "not defined" and "undefined" are synonymous. It appears from your comment that you are making a distinction between the two expressions? Perhaps not.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, what question are you talking about?

Comment: you asked me what is the difference between undefined and not defined

Comment: i'm still learning

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, I do not know the answer. By the way, this was the reason I asked.

Comment: i have also no answer, but i will ask someone in the university

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner , do not bother. I think that there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, $x^{-k}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse of $x$, $x^{-1}$, raised to the $k^{th}$ power. For instance, in $\mathbf{R}$, we have that the inverse of $2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ so that $2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, $2^{-k}=(\frac{1}{2})^k=\frac{1}{2^k}.$ In the case of $0$, there is no multiplicative inverse in $\mathbf{R}$ (or in any field, for that matter), so that the symbol $0^{-1}$ makes no sense. For instance, can you find a real number $r$ so that $r\cdot 0=1$? The answer is no.

In short, $0^{-1}$ does not make sense without further interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, raising $0$ to a negative power implies division by zero, which is undefined. Explicitly, for $a>0$: $$0^{-a}=\frac1{0^a}=\frac10.$$