# Zero to the power of negative numbers

Tags: infinity, calculator

I lately stumbled unto a strange behaviour of my calculator (a TI-Nspire™ CX II-T CAS):
$$
\begin{split}
0^{-2} = 0^{-4} &= \infty         & \forall \text{ even numbers}\\
0^{-1}, 0^{-3} &= \text{undefined} \quad& \forall \text{ odd numbers}\quad&{\scriptsize\text{(note that undefined $\ne$ undefined)}}
\end{split}
$$
To me, either both should result in $\infty$ ($\tilde\infty$ to be precice) or both should be $\text{undefined}$, since both involve division by zero.
Somehow I cannot wrap my head around this, nor find anything about it online.

I've consultated threads like [Why does zero raised to the power of negative one equal infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009868/why-does-zero-raised-to-the-power-of-negative-one-equal-infinity), [Zero to the negative power.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536759/zero-to-the-negative-power/2536767#2536767) and some more, but they all talk about zero by the power of $-1$, nothing else.

Furthermore, I tried it on some online calculators like WolframAlpha, which directly gives me complex infinity ($\tilde \infty$), others said both would be $\text{undefined}$.

Does anyone know how this can be explained?

Comment: As an aside, the words and symbol (though not the basic idea) for "complex infinity" are basically an invention of the Wolfram software team, and are not standard mathematics. The lemniscate with a tilde for that purpose appears in approximately zero textbooks (even those that discuss the Riemann Sphere), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually such expressions are defined as limits, so for example
$$0^{-n} := \lim_{x\to 0} x^{-n}.$$

You'll see that if $n$ is odd, the value of the limit depends on which side zero is approached from ($n$ odd):
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} x^{-n} = -\infty,\quad\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{-n} = +\infty,$$
so the limit is not defined. However, for $n$ even, both one-sided limits agree, and the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{-n}$ exists and is $+\infty$.

While it seems like a bug at first glance, this might be the reason why the calculator produces the observed results - they would be consistent with the above reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hypothesis, as I know nothing about the inner workings of the calculator or the thought process behind its design, or even its capabilities. But my immediate guess would be that the even powers $0^{-2}, 0^{-4}, \ldots$ evaluate to $+\infty$, positive infinity, while the odd powers $0^{-1}, 0^{-3}, \ldots$ evaluate to $\pm\infty$, and therefore not to a single answer, and therefore undefined.